# binary-to-text encoding without lowercase (Base64)?

Tags: hash, character-encoding, binary, base64

I need a **binary-to-text encoding**, like base64, that takes binary and produce text but i **can't have any lowercase letters**.

Anything but lowercase letters. Or anything case unsensitive that i can set to uppercase.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32)

> The resulting character set is all one case, which can often be beneficial when using a case-insensitive filesystem, spoken language, or human memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Uuencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding).  It's like Base64 (in that it represents each 3-byte sequence with 4 symbols), but it uses a different set of 64 symbols, the ASCII characters 0x20 through 0x5F, which doesn't include lowercase.